# filebeat - issues after enable module elasticsearch

Tags: filebeat

I have following issue.
When I'm trying to enable module in filebeat by running command:

```
filebeat modules enable elasticsearch
```

and when I see /modules.d and see that file elastcsearch.yml.disabled is changed to elasticsearch.yml - so everything fine, but when I will restart filebeat I'm getting errors like below.

> ERROR   instance/beat.go:1015   Exiting: Failed to start crawler:
> creating module reloader failed: could not create module registry for
> filesets: error getting config for fileset elasticsearch/audit: Error
> interpreting the template of the input: template: text:3:22: executing
> "text" at <.paths>: range can't iterate over
> /opt/aaa-cluster_audit.json Exiting: Failed to start crawler: creating
> module reloader failed: could not create module registry for filesets:
> error getting config for fileset elasticsearch/audit: Error
> interpreting the template of the input: template: text:3:22: executing
> "text" at <.paths>: range can't iterate over
> /opt/aaa-cluster_audit.json

Can someone help me with that because I don't understand what I'm doing wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

`paths` is supposed to be an array, like so:

```
var.paths: ["/opt/aaa-cluster_audit.json"]
```